# Is there a reason to why some singers don't hold the microphone with their thumb?

Tags: microphones

See these two images

[image]

[image]

They are not using their thumb when they are holding the microphone. Is there a reason for this?

Clarification due to comments: The microphones are not in their stands. The singers are holding them with their hand.

Comment: I think I know what you mean... but they are clearly using their thumb!

Comment: It's hard to tell because the photos are cropped, but are they supporting the microphones with their hands, or are the microphones on stands (with hands resting on top)?

Comment: @Theodore Sorry for the cropping. Didn't think about that. The microphones are not in their stands.

Answer (score 3):

Style points or personal comfort.

Objectively, the proper way to hold a microphone would be to have no part of the hand touching the grille.  What fingers you use does not matter, as long as you don't drop it.

Some singers like to "cup the mic" because they think it makes screams sound more intense, but sound engineers will tell you that keeping your hands off the grille gives the best sound.  In these pictures, both singers are touching the capsule, but not fully cupping it, so the sound would only be slightly affected.  It's possible that sound wasn't a consideration when they grabbed the mic like this.

Comment: Or it's possible that holding the mic like that produces the sound that they want. That's an aesthetic judgment, not an engineering issue.

Comment: @PeteBecker Right... I trimmed it out of the answer, but I was going to make an analogy to how many vocalists tend to drown their voice in effects and hide it under the instruments when they mix their own vocals, because it makes their voice sound less like their own voice.  It is an aesthetic decision, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

As Edward pointed, mic cupping may affect the sound the way the singer likes. There might be some practical reasons holding mic this way is more convenient this way.

However, there is also a good reason not to hold a microphone this way. A directional microphone relies on destructive interference of the sound waves reaching the membrane from the front (singer's side), and via ports located on the rear side of the mic head. Covering these ports with a hand reduces directionality, thus increases the level of the background sounds arriving from the rear. In live situation, this is primarily sound from the the stage monitors, which causes an additional risk of feedback. Use of in-ear monitors, visible in the second photo, can offset this factor.